# gnuplot: plot two data sets from stdin

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having some problems trying to plot two different data sets from stdin in gnuplot... This is the command I'm testing with:

```
% gnuplot -persist <<EOF            
plot '-' index 0 with points, \
'' index 1 with points
1 1.2
2 1.8
3 1.6


1.1 0.8
2.1 0.3
3.1 1.0
EOF
```

Any advise will be very helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should help you

> It’s even possible to read data from standard input multiple times within the same
>   plot command:

```
plot '-', '-'
```

> will read data until an end-of-file character is encoun
>   tered and then expect to read more data (for the second “file”) until finding a second
>   EOF character. Of course, the data entered at a prompt this way can have multiple col
>   umns, from which we can select some with using, and all the other features of the
>   plot command can be used as well.

(from: Philipp K. Janert, Gnuplot In Action)

Comment: I didn't know this. Thanks. This really works: `echo $'1\n2\n3\ne\n4\n5\n6'  | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "-" with lines,"-" with lines'`

Comment: That worked smoothly, this is my final command: 
    % gnuplot -persist <<EOF
    plot '-' with points, \
    '-' with points
    1 1.2
    2 1.8
    3 1.6
    e

    1.1 0.8
    2.1 0.3
    3.1 1.0
    EOF

Thank you much for your help!

Comment: @Cacaroto Vega: Happy that I could help! - Pls mark answered.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot probably wants to reread the input for the second index keyword, but stdin is not seekable. Create a temporary input file.

Comment: Due to disk space limitations, I'd prefer to read from stdin. Do you have another suggestion. Thanks for the quick response..